# Choosing MAX values by the "where=" statement

Tags: sql, sas

Suppose, i have table `A` with columns `a1`, `a2` and `B` table with `b1`, `b2`.

I need to join them like this

```
proc sql;
    create C as
    select a1, b1
    from A as t1
    left join  B( where=(b1=max(select b1 from B)) as t2
        on t1.a2 = t2.b2
run;
```

The problem is in **`where=(a1=max(select a1 from A))`**. It doesn't work somewhy. I need a `where=` solution, because `B` is big and `where=` is really fast

Comment: You are trying to outer join a B record only to those A records for which a1 is the maximum a1 value?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thanks, i edited. Is the answer still relevant?

Comment: Okay, so you want to outer join the B record where b1 is the maximum b1 value and b2 matches a2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition is on the *first* table.  Hence, in a `left join`, such a condition usually goes in the `where` clause.  Conditions on the *second* table would go in the `on` clause.

One method of doing what you want is to use a subquery:

```
proc sql;
    create C as
    select a1, b1
    from A t1 left join
         B t2 
        on t1.a2 = t2.b2
    where t1.a1 = (select max(tt1.a1) from A tt1)
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you only got the syntax wrong. This gets you the B record where b2 matches a2 and b1 is the maximum b1 value in the table.

```
create table c as
  select a.a1, b.b1
  from a
  left join b on b.b2 = a.a2
              and b.b1 = (select max(b1) from b);
```

Or are you simply trying to get the maximum b1 from all B records where b2 matches a2? That would be:

```
create table c as
  select a.a1, max(b.b1)
  from a
  left join b on b.b2 = a.a2
  group by a.a1;
```